# How to add dynamic query parameters to BranchIO link?

Tags: branch.io

Is there a way to specify additional parameters to be passed to the app which are specified by query string?

For example:
`https://app.link/hkljhlkh?nonce=7888809`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering the answer to this on my own.  You can just append query parameters you want and they arrive on your React Native mobile app:

```
branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
  params.nonce # passed through
```

They also appear on the fallback url as query parameters.  Win.

Answer (score 0):

For additional info on adding these link parameters you can refer to https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/#long-links